# Running iMacros for Chrome with VBA

Tags: vba, google-chrome, imacros

I've developed a number of macros that use VBA to open iMacros and scrape / update various websites.  Normally, I use the iMacros browser and occasionally the IE browser.  I'm working on a new macro but the website does respond well to either the iMacros or IE browser.

I'm trying to user iMacros for Chrome.  From what I have read, I should be able to open iMacros for Chrome like this:

```
Set iim1 = CreateObject("imacros")
iret = iim1.iimOpen("-cr", True)
```

However, it isn't working like I expect it to.  It opens Chrome and then after about 60 seconds, it shuts Chrome down without executing any other commands in my macro.

Am I doing something wrong or is something not installed correctly?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  This is the first macro I'm developing with Chrome.

These are the settings I'm currently using:
Office 365 (Excel 2016)
iMacros for Chrome 12.0.501.6698
Windows 10
64 bit OS
Chrome version 77.

Comment: For those interested, + Parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=30582&p=83736#p83682 - With more Info I would think but 1st Answer by @TL has already been accepted in the meantime... (And I don't completely understand why...)

Comment: Test-Test: SOF still buggy-buggy...!? => Yep it is, ah-ah...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an idea to check if your IE thing runs in compatibility mode. I've had same issues with the webbrowser control in VBA using Autocad. Even if IE was installed if I navigate to a website showing the browser version I got Stonehenge old IE6 shown.
So this might also happen in your case. I am quite sure they just utilize the  MS IE Engine. Here is a link which looks outdated but it's all the same:
[Same with Acces upgrade to IE 11](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5615a22-60c5-457f-a5c7-1c39c2ed0bd6/browser-compatibilty-view-issue-from-within-access?forum=accessdev) After I put acad.exe in the registry with the 11000 value Stonehenge was gone :)

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

Add a key with the name of your running executable and the DWORD 11000.
So it just might be an idea to investigate in the same direction.

Comment: Good luck :) That isnt science anymore by MS *grin*

Comment: I don't think that's the correct Answer/Solution (in this Case), see my Reply on the iMacros Forum: https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=30582&p=83736#p83697 - but @OP is apparently happy with it... Hum, OK, even if I didn't really understand "everything"... (And yep, I'm familiar with all IE-Emulation Values in Reg...)

Comment: I did not say that it work in every case. But that it might be worth to give it a try.  It is also a universal problem with this kind of IE DLL calling components which can be solved sometimes like that. And the basic Idea behind is, that the IE component might be in compabillity state. Usually IE11 is not as bad as most Peoples belive.So what is your problem ? Do you solve it ? Do you even try to solve it ?